# Redirecting GREP output to different text files depending on capture content

Tags: grep, io-redirection, tail

I have a logfile with 2 distinct events (among others) that I need to capture.

Each event generates a separate, dedicated line in the logfile with this format:

***timestamp***  -   **PID**  -   **process**  -   **event-type**  -   **event-details**

I don't care much about anything but the ***event-details*** column of the file, and the data I'm expecting to receive there, looks like this:

**Example 1:** `{ "values":{ "SPEED":"7.0" } }`

**Example 2:** `{ "values":{ "CADENCE":"41" } }`

I've been trying to write a shell script that would only read the last line of the logfile every time, and depending on the contents of the ***event-details*** column, redirect the resulting **SPEED** or **CADENCE** data to a specific text file (when I say resulting **SPEED/CADENCE** data I mean the "integer" after the **SPEED":"** expression for example).

So far I was able to redirect the results to two different files, but:

1. I have to "tail" the logfile twice in order for the script to work and...
2. ...as a result of that, I have the feeling that the second file is not being updated at the same rate as the first one...as if, for some reason, I was missing some of the **CADENCE** events due to the order in which the script was written.

I tried using the ***sleep*** function, and also tried to "tail" more than one line at a time to try to mitigate the lack of CADENCE update with no luck.
I just keep missing CADENCE events from time to time.

**A note on the logfile behavior:** Looking at the log, there are 3 events that appear most of the time, and they are always logged in the same order of appearance (CADENCE, SPEED and OTHER), and from time to time there is a 4rd event. I just wanted to clarify that the missing CADENCE events have nothing to do with that "4rd" event appearance.

This is a summarized version of the script that I have currently running:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   tail -1 logfile.txt | grep -oP '(?<=SPEED":")[0-9]+' > spd.txt
   tail -1 logfile.txt | grep -oP '(?<=CADENCE":")[0-9]+' > cad.txt
done
```

**=======UPDATE:=======**

This is the complete log line and ouput expected:

**Example of line 1:**

**Input (from logfile.txt):**

03-16 21:05:28.641 2797-2842/process:Service D/WEBSOCKET: receiving: { "values":{ "Speed MPH":"3.1", "Speed KPH":"4.9", "Miles":"0.551", "Kilometers":"0.886" } }

**Output (sent to spd.txt):**

4.9

**Example of line 2:**

**Input (from logfile.txt):**

03-16 21:05:29.309 2797-2842/process:Service D/WEBSOCKET: receiving: { "values":{ "RPM":"27" } }

**Output: (sent to cad.txt):**

27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Kamaraj, thanks for the help! it was key to find the right answer:

This is the script that what worked for me:

tail -1 logfile.txt | awk -F"\":\"" '{for (c=1;c<=NF;c++) {if ($c ~ /Speed KPH/) {print $(c+1)+0 > "spd.txt"} {if ($c ~ /RPM/) {print $(c+1)+0 > "cad.txt"}}}}'

Had to go back to ***tail -1*** because ***tail -f*** was affected by buffering and it would also leave a trail in the txt file with all the values captured. I was only expecting a single line with the most current result in the output text files.

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

No need of while loop here...

```
tail -f logfile.txt | awk '/SPEED/{print >"spd.txt"}/CADENCE/{print >"cad.txt"}'
```

Comment: Hi Kamaraj, thanks for the help! I just tried with the proposed solution but it is writing the complete log line to the text file. I was wondering if there is a way to only print the resulting Speed/Cadence values.

Comment: please provide the input file contents and the expected output

Comment: Sure! I updated the post with the information. Thanks a lot!